# Apollo broker run error

Tags: java, activemq

I have been trying to create a broker on my activemq apache-apollo 1.7.1 installation. I get the following error:

```
$ apollo-broker run
Startupfailed:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
```

Comment: you will need to supply additional info to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Java 9, install Java 8 along (or instead). Just a cursory google search.

Make sure that `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` include Java 8 when you run your command.